# Add divs with Django template tags on button press

Tags: jquery, django

I have a simple form defined in forms.py:

```
SAMPLE_STRINGS = [('','Select...'),'aa','ab','bb','c0']

class MyCustomForm(forms.Form):
    chosen_string = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SAMPLE_STRINGS, label='Please select a string', required=True)
    chosen_number = forms.IntegerField(label='Please select an integer', widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 0}))
```

I want to allow the user to add boxes (divs) containing the above form. One standalone div, with Django's template tags, would look like this:

```
<div class="box" style="height:auto; background-color: #eee;">
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
    </form>
</div>
```

I know that, if there is a button `<button class="add_box">New Box</button>`, the corresponding jQuery script to add new elements would look like this:

```
$('#button_id').click(function(){
    $('#canvas').append(' ...*HTML of element*... ');
});
```

However, this jQuery doesn't seem to work when the element to be appended doesn't contain pure HTML/CSS but also Django templates.

My views.py:

```
def my_form_func(response):
    form = MyCustomForm(response.POST or None)
    return render(response, "main/my_custom_form.html", {"form": form})
```

my_custom_form.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $( function() {
      $( ".box" ).draggable().resizable();
    } );
    
    // adding div and form on button click - this part causes error
    $('.add_box').click(function(){
        $('#canvas').append('<div class="box" style="height:auto; background-color: #eee;"><form method="get" action="">{% csrf_token %}{{form.as_p}}</form></div>');
    }); 
</script>

<html>
<button class="add_box">New Box</button>

<div id="canvas" style="background-color: #444; height: 90%">
<div class="box" style="height:auto; background-color: #eee;">
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

When I don't include the `$('.add_box')` section, the code runs properly, a dark grey canvas appears with one box in top left corner with the form defined in forms.py. In this case, button press doesn't do anything of course. When including the `$('.add_box')` and omitting the `<div class="box" ... >` section,  button press doesn't add the div with the form that existed there previously.

Is this even possible to do in an easy manner using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because when you render `{{form.as_p}}` it contains line-breaks. If you open your console and see you would have gotten the error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break
```

Moving forward it is not a very great idea to render from Django into javascript for the reasons that:

1. It allows scope for potential XSS attacks.
2. It does not look great, and is an ugly hack.

Then how should we do this? Well why not simply use the HTML as the go between? Render an extra box which will be hidden. Clone this and remove the hidden attributes etc and append it to your div:

```js
$( function() {
    $( ".box" ).draggable().resizable();
} );

// adding div and form on button click - this part causes error
$('.add_box').click(function(){
    // Clone extra box, and remove duplicate ids
    let clone = $("#box-copy").clone().removeAttr("hidden").removeAttr("id");
    clone.find("*").removeAttr("id");
    // If it needs to be resizable and draggable, use below line.
    clone.draggable().resizable();
    // append it to div
    $('#canvas').append(clone);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button class="add_box">New Box</button>


<!-- COPY OF BOX (HIDDEN) -->
<div id="box-copy" class="box" style="height:auto; background-color: #eee;" hidden>
    <form id="test-id" method="get" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
    </form>
</div>


<div id="canvas" style="background-color: #444; height: 90%">
<div class="box" style="height:auto; background-color: #eee;">
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you need to keep one div hidden ? why not clone first div which is already present inside canvas ?

Comment: @Swati for some reason in OP's code with javascript they append a form with the GET method, while in the HTML they render a form with POST method. Well that can be easily resolved but also the fact is then we will have to 1) Reset the form for the inputs that might have been entered in the first div. 2) Adding dynamically means also people might want to _remove_ dynamically, etc. So simply added it an extra time as a hidden element.